# SQL Workbench/J: run SQL file

Tags: sql-workbench-j

I have a sql file (say, abc.sql). 
How can I run same on SQL Workbench/J through GUI.

SQL Workbench/J : Build 123, (2017-09-25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do that:

1. Load the file into an editor (using "File -> Open"), then run the statements of the script from inside the editor (e.g. "Execute all"). Alternatively you can drag the file from your file manager into the editor to load it.
2. Use the [WbInclude](https://www.sql-workbench.eu/manual/wb-commands.html#command-wbinclude) command to run the file without loading it.